# Present Simple with next week

Tags: present-simple

Is this sentence correct? If not, why?

> He **lives** in the flat next week.

I pointed out to my friend that this does not sound right. I said it should be

> He **will live** in the flat next week.

or

> He **is going to live** in the flat next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He lives" is present tense.  It creates a confusing situation where the listener hears present tense in the context of a future event.

"will live" and "is going to live" are both future tense, which makes more sense in the context of the thought you're trying to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct you can't say future things with present indefinite rule.

And then two cases:

1. If you are sure about that he is gonna live there. Then you can use "will live/is going to live".
2. If not sure and just assuming use "may" He may live in the flat from next week.

Hoping it will help.